# Set position of columns in Beamer (R markdown)

Tags: latex, r-markdown, multiple-columns, beamer

I am creating a RMarkdown presentation using Szeged as beamer type. Does anyone know how to set the position of the columns so that there is less space between them? I have the following output:

[image]

the code:

````
---
title: |
    | Text

author: |
        | Name
        | email
        |
        
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true

linkcolor: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


# Workshop

## section
\footnotesize
:::::::::::::: {.columns}
::: {.column}
Text 1

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1

:::
::: {.column}
Text 2

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
:::
::: {.column}
Text 3

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
:::
::::::::::::::
````

But I would the columns to have less space between them so that they are more central, otherwise the text does not fit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the columns:

````
---
title: |
    | Text

author: |
        | Name
        | email
        |
        
date: date

output:
  beamer_presentation:
    theme: Szeged
    slide_level: 2
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: true
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```


# Workshop

## section
\footnotesize
:::::::::::::: {.columns totalwidth=\textwidth}
::: {.column width="30%"}
Text 1

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1

:::
::: {.column width="30%"}
Text 2

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
:::
::: {.column width="30%"}
Text 3

- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
- option 1
:::
::::::::::::::
````

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sam - this works perfectly. Do you know what is the symbol for me to give a line break between the option list and another sentence?

Comment: @DanielaRodrigues After an itemisation, there should be an automatic line break. Can you ask a new question including a [mre] that illustrates what you are trying to do?